# Encode 2 tables with json_encode

Tags: php, json

My function looks like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id1='$id' AND accepted=1 AND notification=1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to select something from another table. How can i do that?

Comment: join both tables

Comment: But how? U mean in $sql?

Comment: Provide more information regarding table structure and data